# What is the best way to store datetime value in documentdb?

Tags: datetime, timezone, azure-cosmosdb

1. Is there a best way to store datetime value in documentdb?
2. Obviously I will be storing this information in UTC and ISO 8601 formats. Are there any gotchas with this?
3. I should be able to query based on this datetime value such startDateTime < currentValue and currentValue <= endDateTime etc. What should I do to get maximum performance on these types of queries etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the only real key that you didn't mention is that you have a range index with full precision (-1) on the ISO-8601 strings.

Some other general guidelines:

- Store all events in canonical form: `2016-07-18T01:23:45.678Z`
- Store everything in zulu/GMT time. End every string with a `Z`. Never store it with `+03:00`. Make sure you shift local time input from the user to zulu time before running queries with that input.
- I also recommend that you use the most coarse granularity for your situation. So, if you are referring to the entire month of march, 2016, simply store `2016-03` leaving off the `-01T00:00:00.000Z`. This mostly applies to the literals you use when running queries. Assuming the events are stored in canonical form than `2016-07 < 2016-07-18T01:23:45.678Z` is true. This recommendation is mostly for the benefit of the user, but it won't cause any performance degradation and it's possible that it could be a very slight improvement in some circumstances.

Comment: What happends if I do not store in UTC format "2016-07-18T01:23:45.678Z"? Eg. "2016-07-18T01:23:45.678" format in local or UTC time?

Comment: If you store it in the local time zone then it will not be sorted by absolute chronology. It will for things in the same timezone though so if everything is going to be in the same timezone, that might work, but in general it's best to store it in zulu time and do the shift to local time once it reaches the client.